# java swing program with multi lingual support

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a TextArea in java where i can write data in chinese. How can I achieve this

Thanks 
Bapi

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718776/how-to-display-japanese-characters-in-jtextarea).

The only thing you have to do is to make sure that the JTextArea uses a font that can display Chinese characters, which the default one unfortunately can't.