# Japanese in JTextArea

Tags: java, database, jtextarea, truetype

I have a database with japanese words. Additionaly i have algorithm that reads these words and put them into JTextArea.
Problem is I see rectangles instead of japanese signs.
But when i copy such a set of rectangles (ctrl+c) from JTA and put them into eg. command input of TotalCommander or Winword document, signs appears are displayed properly. But only under Win7. 
Because i run Eclipse on Virtual Machine under winXP I have ability of copy rectangles also to command input of TotalCommander under winXP. There are remain rectangles as in my Java app.
It means that there is in JTA an info about particular signs, but JTA can't interpretes this info.

Of course I have installed proper font.

I've tried many way with fonts:

```
textArea.setFont(new Font(blablabla));
```

and similar, but without effects.
What should i do?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718776/how-to-display-japanese-characters-in-jtextarea

Comment: I don't agree. This is similar one at most. Besides solution doesn't work. Be aware that i don't need to input any text from keyboard to JTestArea. I need just to display it from external stream.

Comment: Please provide an [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). The problem is probably, that your file-encoding doesn't match UTF8. Can you set the content of your JTextArea programmatically to japanese characters? Then the font itself can't be the problem. I've tried it with Windows XP as well and it just works fine here. http://ideone.com/GDfDbb

Comment: This is not so easy to provide a code because i try to read a big part of MySQL DB (InnoDB).
I don't think that this is UTF problem. In this DB are used russian, german, polish, portugal and there is no problem with them. Only with japanese.
I obviously tried to use Locales/setFont and even other trick but it gaves me nothing.
I use this font: http://www.dafont.com/japanese.font
Can you give me some example how you use code from topic you citated?

Comment: Yes, please see my answer below. The font doesn't contain all japanese characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem with your JTextArea is most-probably, that the font you're using isn't applicable for UTF-8 & Japanese. The font doesn't provide an mapping table from UTF-8 values to characters. i.e. 0x41 is in ASCII, as well as in UTF-8 and even SHIFT-JIS the letter 'A' - but the Font you're just linking, resolves 0x41 to an Kanji character. And the whole font doesn't contain Hiragana and Katakana characters at all - please see also the comments section on the site where you got this font from [here](http://www.dafont.com/font-comment.php?file=japanese).

> After using ChapMap it has a WSIfonts TAG and does ＮＯＴ！　support ALL the Chinese characters it only has 90 characters and assigns 1 character per Char except Caps.

It's a chinese font - not a Japanese one. But it won't even provide all chinese characters and has no useful mapping table included - so it's pretty useless.

Try to use another font - that should work just fine, if it contains really japanese characters and provides an applicable mapping table for UTF-8.

You can find fonts, that would work i.e. [here](http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Japanese.html)

Comment: This solves my problem. 
Indeed Japanese.ttf is a crap.
This one is a good one:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/monafont/?source=dlp
Thank you very much.